# Evaluating a quadratic character sum.

Tags: number-theory, finite-fields

I am trying to prove the following "well-known" identity. (I cannot seem to find a proof! Possibly the proofs  are written in a more sophisticated way (involving Jacobi sums I think)-so I am not able to work out what is happening!

Assume that ${\bf F}_q$ is a finite field of odd characteristic, and assume that $\chi$ is the quadratic character on ${\bf F}_q$. Then, if $f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c$ is a quadratic polynomial in ${{\bf F}_q}[x]$, the following identity holds :
$$ {S_{f}}={{\sum}_{x\in {\bf F}_q}}{\chi (ax^2 +bx + c)} = \begin{cases} -{\chi}(a) & \text{if $b^2 - 4ac \neq 0$} \\
 {\chi}(a)(q-1) & \text{if $b^2 - 4ac = 0$} \end{cases} $$
I completed the square, and rewrote $${a^{-1}}f(x)=x^2+{\frac{b}{a}}x+{\frac{c}{a}}={\frac{(2ax+b)^2}{4a^2}}-{\frac{b^2 - 4ac}{4a^2}}.$$ Thus, $${S_{f}}={{\sum}_{x\in{\bf F}_q}}{\chi (ax^2 +bx + c)}\\\\ =
{\chi}(a){{\sum}_{x\in {\bf F}_q}}{\chi}((2ax+b)^2- (b^2 - 4ac)).$$ Now if $b^2 - 4ac =0$, then in evaluating $S_{f}$ we are just adding up $\chi (a)$ to itself $(q-1)$ times (the character is defined to take value $0$ at $0$), so that part of the identity is clear. Unless I am mistaken, if I prove that for $D\neq 0$, with $D\in {\bf F}_q$ $${{\sum}_{x\in {\bf F}_q}}{\chi (x^2 - D)} =-1.$$ This seems to give me the result I have to prove. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I actually expected this to have been covered alredy on the site. As I didn't find a close enough match, I decided to post an answer. [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/183097/11619) is related, but...

Comment: More material [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4715930/11619)

Answer (score 1):

One way (rather standard, I think):

Consider the equation
$$x^2-D=y^2\qquad(*)$$
with $D$ as in your post and $x,y$ ranging over $\mathbf{F}_q$. Denote by $N(D)$ the number of solutions $(x,y)$ of $(*)$.

A key ingredient is that $(*)$ is equivalent to
$$(x-y)(x+y)=D.$$
Because we are in odd characteristic, the linear transformation $(x,y)\mapsto (x+y,x-y)$ is  bijective. Denoting $u=x+y$, $v=x-y$ we see that $N(D)$ is equal to the number of solutions of
$$uv=D\qquad(**)$$
with $u,v\in\Bbb{F}_q$. But, to a given non-zero choice of $u$, $(**)$ determines
$v$ uniquely, so we can conclude that $N(D)=q-1$.

On the other hand, to a fixed $x$ the number of solutions $y$ of $(*)$ is equal to
$1+\chi(x^2-D)$. This is because there is a single $y$, when $x^2-D=0$, two solutions when $x^2-D$ is a non-zero square, and no solutions when $x^2-D$ is a non-square. Summing over $x$ we arrive at the alternative answer
$$
N(D)=\sum_x(1+\chi(x^2-D))=q+\sum_x\chi(x^2-D).
$$
The claim follows from the earlier result $N(D)=q-1$.

Comment: I worked out a proof which was longer, and was wondering if I should post it. But your proof is much simpler and cleaner, and gets to heart of the matter quickly! So I will refrain so as not to waste space. Incidentally, in the case that the field is the prime field ${\bf {F}}_{p}$ where $p$ is an odd prime number, the quadratic character is the Legendre symbol, and this sum is apparently called a *Jacobsthal sum*

Comment: Questions like this often hinge on whether it is easier to count the number of solutions of an equation, or to evaluate a character sum. Often bounds on character sums give useful information about the number of solutions, but that street has traffic in both directions!

Comment: Useful insight!! Thanks. Am trying to read a paper by T. Ono in which for some elliptic curves over finite fields sharper bounds than the Hasse-Weil bound have been found.